# Сумма чисел с точкой / среднее значение чисел с точкой в Google Таблицах

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Скажите, как считать числа с точками (не запятой) при наличии условий (одного или нескольких):

1. Сумму чисел
2. Среднее значение. Например, по аналогии формулы =СРЗНАЧЕСЛИ(C2:C;"BUY";F2:F)

Comment: Откуда считать?

Comment: 1 - Поменять на правильный десятичный разделитель. 2 - Считать.

Comment: Считать из гугл таблиц. Данные обновляются ежедневно и каждый день вручную не хотелось бы менять точки на запятые. Есть ли соответствующие формулы, что-бы считать с точками?